# How to round a float value

Tags: ruby, rounding

I'm trying to round a float value as follows:

```
(0.11 + 0.22 + 0.23 / 3).round(2)
```

Does anyone know if there is other effective way to round up?

Comment: Wait, where's the `OrderedHash`? The problem can't be in the segment you showed us, unless someone redefined `Float#+`.

Comment: I'm guessing those numbers are not hardcoded. Where do they come from?

Comment: Why did you remove the error message? Like this the question doesn't make sense. `(0.11 + 0.22 + 0.23 / 3).round(2)` works fine.

Comment: Actually it's not a problem, am asking that Is other effective way to round a float value instead of doing (0.11 + 0.22 + 0.23 / 3).round(2) this !

Comment: So… what's the problem? Is it just that you think calling `round` is too complicated?

Comment: no, its not too complicated, i was just thinking if there is any other way !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to round up and never down, you can do this:

```
(0.411 * 100).ceil / 100.0 # => 0.42
```

Otherwise just use `round`. Or use the string formatter if you don't mind your float turning into a string.

Answer (score 2):

The main ways to round a floating point number in Ruby are via the [`Float#round` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round) or the [`String#%` (format) operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25).  For example:

```ruby
f = (0.11 + 0.22 + 0.23 / 3) # => 0.4066666666666667
f.round(2)  # =>  0.41
"%.02f" % f # => "0.41"
```