# Python3, round() type inconsistent. Proper way to round a float value to index a list or an array

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, indexing, rounding

I precise that I am aware of the concepts about decimal representation and the supposedly relevant questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716057/how-to-round-a-float-value), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968097/python-float-vs-numpy-float32) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), and the suggested [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Still **I am astonished that in Python3 `round()` sometimes returns an integer** (as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#round)) **and sometimes a float** (weird to me), **depending upon an unsignificant difference in the *type* of its *first* argument**.

I understand that, e.g., `floor()` or `ceil()` *always* return a float, and of course I found reasonable that `round(x, digits)` returns an integer or a float  depending on the second parameter `digits` being specified or not, and even that different implementations of `round` exist (e.g. the `builtin` and the `numpy` one).

Specifically, **the following code shows that a `float32` and a `numpy.float32` make `round()` return different types**:

```
    >>> x=101/100
    >>> x
    1.01
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> nx=np.float32(x)
    >>> nx
    1.01
    >>> round(x)
    1
    >>> round(nx)
    1.0
```

For the curious, I get my `x` value as the prediction of a classification model in Keras, and need to obtain an index out of it, by rounding to the nearest integer, to select the right label out of a list of strings.

And a search in StackOverflow/Stackexchange doesn't reveal the matter was already treated. Pls give me a helpful link in case.

To be more specific, I am getting a predicted value out of a Neural Network classifier, i.e. a number approaching either 0 or 1 or another integer, and want to use it as an index to print the correct label associated to the prediction (it should be an almost basic need).

The solution is quite simple, although ugly: `int(round(x))` (also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371424/round-a-float-and-convert-it-to-an-integer-in-a-python2-and-python3-compatible-m)); but I still consider it a kind of workaround to an undesired behaviour.

I know that *why does this work so* questions are not appreciated, so let's ask *what* is the correct pythonic way to obtain that integer and that label out of a `numpy.float32` value, in the hope that somebody unveils also an interesting rationale behind this ...ehm... functionality.

Comment: It returns the closest integer and otherwise delegates to __round__. Never says that the type should an integer though...

Comment: If I understood correctly you want another way of casting to the nearest integer that is not `int(round(x))` ?

Comment: This behaviour is NumPy's choice, not Python's, and part of the rationale is backwards compatibility constraints. See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11810 and issues linked from it for further discussion.

Comment: I often use int(x+0.5).  I generally want the financial rounding (0.5 rounds up) that I'm used to,  not the nearest even int for which 0.5 rounds to 0, 1.5 rounds to 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`round` delegates to the object's `__round__` method.

```
In [367]: x = 123.34
In [368]: x.__round__()
Out[368]: 123
In [369]: np.float64(x).__round__()
Out[369]: 123.0
```

Apparently this numpy round returns a matching type

```
In [376]: type(np.float(x).__round__())
Out[376]: int
In [377]: type(np.float32(x).__round__())
Out[377]: numpy.float32
In [378]: type(np.float64(x).__round__())
Out[378]: numpy.float64
In [379]: type(np.int32(x).__round__())
Out[379]: numpy.int32
```

So `int(round(x))` probably is the cleanest way of making sure you have an integer if there's a possibility that `x` is one of the numpy floats.